# What is the problem with eclipse AVRdude?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, avr, signature

I was working on eclipse and all was good until suddenly when i choose mcu load it gives me this error and i cannot find the problem

Could not understand the output from AVRDude.

Either avrdude returned an error message that is not covered by the AVR Eclipse.

Pluguin

- or you have a newer AVRDude version with a changed output format,

In either case check the AVRDude return message below and contact
the AVR Eclipse Plugin maintainers to have this fixed.
hitps://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-eclipse/

Reason:
Could not find a valid Signature in the avrdudie output

I tried to reinstall usbasp driver and paths of eclipse and nothing changed

Also i tried another kit and the same issue happened

Comment: Have you tried looking on the support site https://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-eclipse/ as suggested in the message? There seems to be plenty of discussion about things there.